# ansible jinja2 seperate certain interfaces from list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm new to jinja and ansible, and am still trying to wrap my head around how to work with them.
In my case, I'm trying to get a sublist of interface names, where I can execute a certain action on if the description key contains a certain value.

I tried things with an if map construction, but that did seem to work out.
Any suggestion how to do this?

I have the following

```yaml
- hosts: Router1
  gather_facts: false
  connection: network_cli

  tasks:
  - name: get interfaces
    arista.eos.eos_interfaces:
      state: gathered
    register: all_interfaces

  - name: check debug
    debug:
       msg: "{{ all_interfaces.gathered }}"

  - name: only configured by Ansible ports
    set_fact:
      interface: >
        {% if 'Configured by Ansible' in all_interfaces.gathered|map(attribute='description')%}
        {% endif %}

  - name: check debug
    debug:
       msg: "{{ interface }}"
```

The list printed out (and which I try to use)

```json
    [
        {
            "description": "Router2",
            "enabled": true,
            "mode": "layer3",
            "name": "Port-Channel1000"
        },
        {
            "description": "Router2",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Ethernet1"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Ethernet2"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Ethernet3"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Ethernet4"
        },
        {
            "description": "Configured by Ansible",
            "enabled": false,
            "name": "Ethernet5"
        },
        {
            "description": "Configured by Ansible",
            "enabled": false,
            "name": "Ethernet6"
        },
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Ethernet7"
        },
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Ethernet8"
        },
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Loopback0"
        },
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Management0"
        },
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "name": "Management1"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: => `{{ all_interfaces.gathered | selectattr('description', '==', 'Configured by ansible') }}`

Comment: yes thanks. that helped. It became the following
`{{ all_interfaces.gathered | selectattr('description', 'defined') | selectattr('description', 'eq', 'Configured by Ansible') |map(attribute='name') |list }}`

Comment: You are encouraged to answer and accept your own question, to show others the solution that worked for you